# Parent/child relationship in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, collection, model, category-tree

I am adding a custom "category" model with children items in my module.

To add children I need to fetch collection from this "mycategories" module. How do I get a collection of categories when adding children items to show in a dropdown in the backend?

I tried using the model collection factory method:

```
$collection = $this->mymodulemodelFactory->create();
```

But I think it is for getting collection of the same model.

**Note**: By category and its children, i dont mean that they are Magento Catalog categories. They can be anything like Palettes and colors, Font family and fonts etc.

Comment: I edited your question and title based on your comment, to make clear that it is not about Magento categories.  I'm still not sure how "show in a dropdown" and "add children" is relevant since you are asking for how to **fetch a collection**. If you need more help, please add more specific information about what you have and what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

#### List of all categories with sub-categories as an option array (with opt-group):

If you want to get the category tree, just use the method `toOptionArray` of the `\Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options` class located in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/Component/Product/Form/Categories/Options.php` like this:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options
 */
protected $categoriesOptions;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options $categoriesOptions
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options $categoriesOptions
) {
    $this->categoriesOptions = $categoriesOptions;
}

public function getCategories()
{
    $values = $this->categoriesOptions->toOptionArray();

    return $values;
}
```

Result in this case should look like this (options with opt-groups):

[image: Options with option groups]

---

#### List of all categories as an option array:

Try this:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory
 */
protected $categoryFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
) {
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
}

public function getCategories()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');
    $values = $collection->toOptionArray(); // or use method toArray

    return $values;
}
```

Result should look like this:

[image: result array]

---

#### List of all categories with data as an array:

To get all the category data just replace `toOptionArray()` to `toArray()`:

```
$values = $collection->toArray();
```

[image: toArray result]

Comment: @HungryDB Does my answer helped you?

Comment: i am not asking about Magento categories, i just want to show dropdown items as collection of another module.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement this parent-child relationship and a method like `getChildCollection()` yourself.

Usually you will have a database column `parent_id` and to load the children of a given parent, you filter by the parent id.

#### Example method for a resource model:

```
public function getChildCollection($parent)
{
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $parent->getId());
    return $collection;
}
```